# Case sensitive logon on some users with Oracle 12.1

Tags: oracle, passwords, oracle12c

Looking for a way to let selected users have case-sensitive logon check on Oracle 12.1. Setting SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = TRUE enables all users to have case sensitive logon, but trying to limit that to some.

Defining a profile having a verify function which checks for at least one upper and lower letter seems to only check when changing the password, but not upon logon.

Comment: Even with `SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = TRUE` the account remains case insensitive **if** the account was created when case-sensitive was still off and the password has not been changed. As soon as the user changes the password it becomes case-sensitive. And new users have also case-sensitive passwords.

Comment: Are you referring to the password type only being set to 10G, which does not support case sensitive password? Is there a way to force 10G only on a 12.1 database?